# On error swap to another observable after atleast one successful response

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I'm using Observables of rxjs to communicate with a device which is accessible over HTTP. The HTTP-calls are started before the device is completely online, so therefore some calls can fail at the beginning. At some point the device is online, an update is started and the progress is polled periodically. At the end of the update the device has to restart and will afterwards provide the progress on a different url.

Now I want to map this behaviour with rxjs:

```
successfulCall: boolean = false;  

testGet() {
    return Observable.timer(0, 1000)
      .concatMap(() => this.http.get(this.url))
      .map(response => {
        let result: string = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(response.arrayBuffer()));
        this.successfulCall = true;
        return result;
      })
      .timeout(2000)
      .retryWhen(errors => {

        if (this.successfulCall) {
          return Observable.throw("offline");
        }
        else {
          return errors.delay(2000);
        }

      })
      .onErrorResumeNext(this.observableTwo);
```

My idea is to use `retryWhen` as a switch, which then can chose the other observable. But the second observable is never started, only the first one is called. Dependent on the device status (online or offline) I either receive timeouts or valid answers and the calls continue. I also know that an exception in the normal control flow is not a very pretty idea.

I made a little flowchart to visualize my idea, because I could imagine that my description of the problem could be to complicated.

*wasSuccessful have to be initialized with false and the processing of the observable results is not shown*

[image: Flowchart of Observable]

Also other (maybe prettier/better)  approaches are perfectly okay, I just want to solve the problem and do not have to insist on my approch.

Comment: +1 for the diagram flow. However the best here is to do a marble diagram so the relationship between the input streams and output stream is clearly spelled out. Your current diagram for instance misses the timing information (polling).

Answer (score 0):

So you want to poll your remote device until it comes online and after that initial bootup has succeeded continue with the update process after which it goes offline and you want to start polling again.

```js
// mock implementation of polling until succes
var attempts = 0;
function startUp() {
  attempts++;
  if(attempts < 10) {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(new Error('NOT BOOTED YET'));
  }
  attempts = 0;
  return Rx.Observable.of('remote device online');
}

const bootupPollingSource = Rx.Observable.of('')
  .concatMap(_ => 
     Rx.Observable.defer(() => startUp())
     .do(null, err => console.log('[debug] bootup err:' + err.message))
     .retryWhen(attempts => attempts.delay(100))
  );

const regularOperationsSource = Rx.Observable.from(['starting update','...','...'])
  .concat(Rx.Observable.throw(new Error('device is rebooting')))
  .catch(err => bootupPollingSource)

bootupPollingSource
  .concat(regularOperationsSource)
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log, () => console.log('completed'));
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```